# Mute/UnMute WebRTC stream while playing in Ant Media's WebRTC iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, webrtc-ios, ant-media-server-sdk

I'm using [WebRTC-iOS-SDK](https://github.com/ant-media/WebRTC-iOS-SDK) to play the live stream in iOS device. I want to mute/unmute the incoming live stream however I cannot make it even if I try several methods such as `setAudioTrack` or something. Could you please tell me how I can mute/unmute the audio when I'm playing the stream in WebRTC-iOS-SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain how to mute and unmute the incoming stream.

- Let's assume that you're publishing a live stream to Ant Media Server with a stream id `stream1`
- Let's assume again that you're playing that stream with WebRTC-iOS-SDK as explained in this [blog post at Step 4:Play WebRTC Live Stream in iOS](https://antmedia.io/build-and-try-webrtc-ios-app-for-dummies/)
- Call the following method to mute the playing stream after live stream has started

```swift
  self.antMediaClient?.enableAudioTrack(trackId: "stream1", enabled: false);
```

You can give `true` in the second parameter to unmute the audio track again.

You can use the `enableVideoTrack` in the same way. The good thing is that when you call these methods, you make server to enable/disable sending streams. It means that you can decrease network usage if it's important for you.

Cheers